# upload multiple files at once from google drive to google cloud storage

Tags: python-3.x, google-drive-api, google-cloud-storage, google-api-python-client

my objective is to identify some files in google drive and upload them sequentially to a google storage bucket.  I am using a google 'cloud function' to do this and have already done tests to confirm that the connection is working properly.

The issue I have seems to relate to how I get the name of the file - it is returning a 'none type' value.  Please see my code below

```
    import os.path
    from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
    from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
    from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
    from googleapiclient.discovery import build
    from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
    from google.cloud import storage
    import io
    from googleapiclient import discovery
    from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
    import google.auth
    import re
    import logging
    
    # Confirming Oauth for Drive API# 
    SCOPES = [ 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
    creds, project = google.auth.default(scopes=SCOPES)
    service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
    
    # Confirming Oauth #
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    ## target Bucket #
    bucket_name = 'my-bucket'
    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)

    get_bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    team_drive_loc = 
    'https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/xxxxxxxxxxx'
    team_drive_parent_folder ='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxA'
    #bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    
    
    query= "name contains 'Customer' and name contains '2022'    "
    drive_files = service.files().list(q= query,
                                 driveId =team_drive_parent_folder,
                                 supportsAllDrives= True,
                                 includeItemsFromAllDrives= True,
                                 corpora ='drive',fields="files(id,name)").execute()

    for file in drive_files:

            source_file_name =service.get(fileId=fileId, fields="files(name)").execute()["files(name)"]
            bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
            blob = bucket.blob("incoming/iri/IRI_Updates/Ongoing_Sales_Data/2022/" + 
            source_file_name)
            blob.upload_from_filename(source_file_name)
            logging.info('Uploaded {} ...'.format(source_file_name))
```

...And this is the error i get.  If anyone can help me source the file name correctly and upload to the gcs bucket, that would be great

`Exception on / [POST] Traceback (most recent call last): File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2073, in wsgi_app response = self.full_dispatch_request() File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1518, in full_dispatch_request rv = self.handle_user_exception(e) File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1516, in full_dispatch_request rv = self.dispatch_request() File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1502, in dispatch_request return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args) File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.7/site-packages/functions_framework/__init__.py", line 171, in view_func function(data, context) File "/workspace/main.py", line 86, in iri_data_sync source_file_name =service.get(fileId=fileId, fields="files(name)").execute()["files(name)"] AttributeError: 'Resource' object has no attribute 'get'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is telling you the issue

> 'Resource' object has no attribute 'get'

its not `service.get` its `service.files().get`

```
source_file_name =service.files().get(fileId=fileId, fields="files(name)").execute()["files(name)"]
```

you actually had it right with `service.files().list`  you just removed forgot it with the get request.

Comment: thanks for spotting that!  My problem now however is that the ```get``` method requires a fileID  first before returning the name of the file.  How would I first obtain the fileID in order for me to the return the name?

Comment: would it be something close to this?                                                                                   ```    for file in drive_files:
            source_file_id = service.files().get(fileid= file('id'),fields="files(id)").execute() # gets file id
            #source_file_name = service.files().get(fileId=source_file_id, fields="files(name)").execute()["files(name)"]
            source_file_name =service.files().get(fileId=source_file_id,fields="files(name)").execute()["files(name)"]```

Comment: I think you should just run the except into a response object then print out what's in that.  If your not seeing the name maybe there is something wrong with how you are reading it.  Check how they are reading the name in the [sample](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/quickstart/python)